# Rendering FBML (sometimes)

Tags: facebook, fbml, xfbml

anyone knowing a reason why my application, only renders name.. profile.. but not the eventlink? (it's an iframe application)

```
<fb:name uid="123123" capitalize="true" /><br />
<fb:profile-pic uid="123123" linked="true" /><br />
<fb:eventlink eid="321321321321" /><br />
```

thx sven

Comment: In which way you are formatting the tag ??Its importent please go through http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/eventlink/

Comment: Is this a FB app, or is it a FB Connect app?

Comment: aehm it's a app, using iframe..